# Django - How to simply get domain name?

Tags: python, django, host, hostname

Firstly, I want to say that I'm a beginner in Django.

I'm looking for a simple way to retrieve the domain name of my Django website.

I want to do this in my settings.py. I've already tried with the socket something like this:

> socket.gethostname()

but this doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a request object,do

```
request.META['HTTP_HOST']
```

This would return the hostname

Comment: Probably better to use `request.get_host()` ([docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host)), since HTTP_HOST is not the only way to find the host name.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `django.contrib.sites` framework:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

your_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform
platform.node()
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html):

> "Returns the computer’s network name (may not be fully qualified!). An
>   empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined."

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how this would work in the case of virtual hosts / server blocks. Does it? If so...how?

Comment: Won't work with virtual hosts.